# how to show 9 other result in differnt page

Tags: php, regex, phpmyadmin

hi this reads the data from database  this code shows 10 result so if i click on first result  the other 9 result should me on a different page how do should do that

```
$sql = "
        SELECT title, id,summary
        FROM course
        WHERE title like '%$id%'
        LIMIT 10
    ";
    $res = $m->query($sql);
    if ($res) {
        while($row = $res->fetch_array()){
            $results[] = $row;
        }
    <?php if (count($results) > 0){ ?>
    <ul>

        <li><?=count($results)?></li>
        <?php foreach ($results as $result){ ?>
        <li><a href="detail.php?ide=<?= $result['id'] ?>"><?=    $result['title'] ?></a></li>
                <p> <?=$result['summary'] ?></p>


        <?php } ?>
    </ul>   
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Please consider rephrasing your question so that we can better understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: this code shows 10 result so if i click on first result  the other 9 result related results should show  me on a different page

Comment: look up "pagination"

Comment: `SELECT title, id,summary
        FROM course
        WHERE title like '%$id%' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10`

Comment: i don"t need pagination beacuse i putten a link show me decription i want to show that related result in that page

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `LIMIT 11, 10` or `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 11` in your Query, see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

But nobody here is going to write the URL parameter stuff for the pagination for you. That would be a bit lazy, don't you think?

Comment: well i am saying to write me answer but how should start which where details page other stuff<li><a href="detail.php?ide=<?= $result['id'] ?>"><?=    $result['title'] ?></a></li>

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really getting what you're asking for! =/

Comment: ahh for eg if i click on second result right the 9 other result should show in detail page  or if click on  forth result the other the other 9 results  should show me on detail page